# Application Gateway for Containters and SignalR

Tags: azure, containers, signalr, azure-aks, gateway

Anybody knows how to configure Application Gateway for Containters so that SignalR application could be hosted behind it?

I am doing tests with [Orlean's Voting demo application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/orleans-voting-sample-app-on-kubernetes/).

Setting Application Gateway for Containers in the way shown in Application Gateway for Containers  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/for-containers/quickstart-deploy-application-gateway-for-containers-alb-controller) makes the application show for a moment than message "Attempting to reconnect to the server: 1 of 8". Than message disappears (application's page is visible again) than the same message appears again. And so on. A reconnection loop.

To rule out backplane problems I have scaled the application down to only 1 replica. The same problem appears.

To rule out application problems I have configured the application to be visible using azure load balancer as well. Accessing it by load balancer's ip works.

So it looks like a problem with Application Gateway for Containers configuration. Any hints how to allow it passing SignalR?

Edit:
In case anybody wanted to deploy the demo application in the way similar to mine. Here is how I did it (following the installation steps of application gateway for containers and voting application that there done like described by the documentation). All the steps looks like they work, just signalr doesn't.

1. yaml file declaring a service in kubernetes that defines how to access the application. it's version without load balancer.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: votingapp
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
  - name: https
    port: 433
  - name: orleans-dashboard
    port: 8888
  selector:
    app: votingapp
```

2. Opening a gateway in Kubernetes. I have installed ALB in 'bring your own' method so I need to refer to it's Id. I'm dynamically creeating yaml from power shell here.

```
$resourceGroup = 'votingapp'
$agfcName = 'alb-test'
$frontendName = 'test-frontend'

$resourceId = $(az network alb show --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $agfcName --query id -o tsv)

echo "apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway-01
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    alb.networking.azure.io/alb-id: $resourceId
spec:
  gatewayClassName: azure-alb-external
  listeners:
  - name: http-listener
    port: 80
    protocol: HTTP
    allowedRoutes:
      namespaces:
        from: Same
  addresses:
  - type: alb.networking.azure.io/alb-frontend
    value: $frontendName
" | kubectl apply -f -
```

3. Opening httproute:

```
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: traffic-split-route
  namespace: default
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - name: gateway-01
  rules:
  - backendRefs:
    - name: votingapp
      port: 80
```

4. Configuring session affinity to make sure each client is always connected to the same server application (it's not needed during the test as it's only using 1 replica, but oh well):

```
apiVersion: alb.networking.azure.io/v1
kind: RoutePolicy
metadata:
  name: session-affinity-route-policy
spec:
  targetRef:
    kind: HTTPRoute
    name: traffic-split-route
    namespace: default
    group: ""
  default:
    sessionAffinity: 
      affinityType: "application-cookie"
      cookieName: "aff"
      cookieDuration: 3600s
```

Comment: Can you kindly refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-work-with-app-gateway and see if this is helpful?

Comment: Using Azure SignalR service works. Also if I alter the way SignalR hub in the application works, so that SignalR traffic goes through Azure Load Balancer (it is available to end user's browsers at different IP address then) then it works as well. It's just Application Gateway for Containers that doesn't want to work with SignalR.